# Change Font Style when writing Code, Math, .. in Pages

Tags: pages, iwork, word-processor

Is it possible to quickly switch between font styles when writing different types of text. For example when I write code or mathematical text I'd like to use a different font, eventually a background.

So far I only know how to add paragraph styles which change the whole paragraph obviously, not just a few characters.

It'd be great if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you’re looking for is called **Character Styles**. It works similarly to **Paragraph Styles**, except that it only affect the character you’ve selected. To create a paragraph style:

1. Select characters you want to define the style for (eg. math formula, code)  and change the background, font type, or font color according to your preferences.
2. Open up **Text Inspector Pane** (it’s under the same panel in Pages 5.x), or you might need to dig around for Pages 4.x. You should be able to see some default character styles such as ALL CAPS, Emphasis, and Underline. See screenshots.
3. From the list of styles, choose the `+` sign at the top right and name your newly created style. Apply this for all your future selected characters.

Here’s the screenshot for the list of **Character Styles**.

[image: Pages 5.0 Character Styles]

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a way to add a shortcut to those Styles like for example command + b for bold?

Comment: Unfortunately the character style selection is not available in Menu Bar, so no custom shortcuts can be made. Although we can do it with Keyboard Maestro by using image detection.